# Read / write to folders with AWS and R

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am trying to use the free version of `Amazon Web Services EC2` with `Ubuntu` and `R`.  I created a simple `R` file I hope will read a small `CSV` input data file in one folder, perform a trivial operation and write the output to a `CSV` file in a separate folder.  However, the output `CSV` file is not being created.

Here are the contents of the `R` file:

```
my.data <- read.csv('/my_cloud_input_file_test/my_input_test_data_Nov22_2019.csv')

my.data$c <- my.data$a + my.data$b

write.csv(my.data, '/my_cloud_output_file_test/my_output_test_data_Nov22_2019.csv', row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Here are the contents of the input data file:

```
a,b
100,12
200,22
300,32
400,42
500,52
```

Here are the only two lines I used in `PuTTY` after connecting to the `instance`:

```
ubuntu@ip-122-31-22-243:~$ sudo su
root@ip-122-31-22-243:/home/ubuntu# R CMD BATCH Cloud_test_R_file_Nov22_2019.R
```

The `R` file is located in the `ubuntu` folder according to `FileZilla`, as are my input and output folders.

Can someone please point out my mistake?  If I put the `R` file and input data set both in the `ubuntu` folder then the output data set is created in the `ubuntu` folder without me having to use a `setwd` statement (after I modify the `read.csv` and `write.csv` statements to eliminate my input and output folder names).  So, I am not using a `setwd` statement here.  If I need a `setwd` statement here what should it be?

Sorry for such a trivial question.

Comment: The path looks absolute but you are looking for it relative.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked:

```
setwd('/home/ubuntu/')

my.data <- read.csv('retest_input_data/my_input_data_Nov24_2019.csv')

my.data$c <- my.data$a + my.data$b

write.csv(my.data, 'retest_output_data/my_output_data_Nov24_2019.csv', row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

`PuTTY` line:

```
ubuntu@ip-122-31-22-243:~$ R CMD BATCH retest_R_file_Nov24_2019.R
```